# doxygen creates empty data for Tcl code file

Tags: tcl, doxygen

I am using the standard version in RH5.5
These are the only tcl file (sample.tcl) contents:

```
##general procs used for CCK coding
#use set varname rather than return $varname
#\code
##Documented proc DlgLgrep \c
#accepts a list, and an expression. Returns a list of all elements for list,which match expression
#The expression is carried out in the DlgLgrep contect and local namespace. You can, of course use
#upvar and uplevel within your code.
#for example, let us say that you want numbers that are above 3
#puts [ DlgLgrep { $grepy > 3 }  { 1 4 0 8 -2 } ]
#will yield
#4 8
proc DlgLgrep { expry listy  } {
    #accepts a list, and an expression. Returns a list of all elements for list,which match expression
     #The expression is carried out in the DlgLgrep contect and local namespace. You can, of course use
     #upvar and uplevel within your code.
     #for example, let us say that you want numbers that are above 3
     #puts [ DlgLgrep { $grepy > 3 }  { 1 4 0 8 -2 } ]
     #will yield
     #4 8
    set ret  {}
    foreach grepy $listy {
              if { [ expr  $expry ] } {
                            lappend ret $grepy
              }
    }
    return $ret
}
#\endcode
```

These are the doxygen file contents:

```
PROJECT_NAME           = CCK_DLG
PROJECT_NUMBER         =
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
USE_WINDOWS_ENCODING   = NO
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       =
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        =
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    =
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
DETAILS_AT_TOP         = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 8
ALIASES                =
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = YES
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       =
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_DIRECTORIES       = NO
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    =
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           =
INPUT                  = ./
FILE_PATTERNS          =
RECURSIVE              = NO
EXCLUDE                = *.tcl
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       =
EXAMPLE_PATH           =
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       =
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             =
INPUT_FILTER           =
FILTER_PATTERNS        =
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = NO
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          =
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            =
HTML_FOOTER            =
HTML_STYLESHEET        =
HTML_ALIGN_MEMBERS     = YES
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               =
HHC_LOCATION           =
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = NO
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4wide
EXTRA_PACKAGES         =
LATEX_HEADER           =
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
USE_PDFLATEX           = NO
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    =
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    =
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_LINKS              = NO
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_SCHEMA             =
XML_DTD                =
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX =
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           =
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  =
PREDEFINED             =
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      =
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
TAGFILES               =
GENERATE_TAGFILE       =
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = NO
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = NO
CALLER_GRAPH           = NO
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
DOT_PATH               =
DOTFILE_DIRS           =
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_WIDTH    = 1024
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_HEIGHT   = 1024
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
```

this is a small excerpt, of course. I am a newbie, and no-one where I work has done any doxygen work.
Thanks!

Comment: RH is know for having an old version of doxygen installed (I don't know by head which version it is you can find this by starting: doxygen -v, it will give you the version or when it is an old version a help overview), and RH5 is some years old too. Please check what happens if you use a more modern version. A point that is certainly wrong is that the \code and \endcode are in 2 different comment blocks, resulting in: warning: reached end of comment while inside a @code block; check for missing @@endcode tag! Please have a look at the \snippet command, I'm not sure if this works for TCL